# Heroku: Uploading a static site on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku

I'm building my portfolio and made simple etch-a-sketch project with HTML/CSS and Javascript. I'm trying to host the site on Heroku but i'm getting this error:

```
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

This is basically a static site, I don't really need a buildpack, is there any way I can still push what I have to Heroku?

Comment: Try with this one: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is normally used for deploying apps, not static sites. I find using GitHub pages to be much easier for static site hosting. If your project is already on GitHub just go to the settings tab of your repo, scroll to the GitHub pages section, and select which branch of your repo you want to deploy. **edit - Just make sure your home html file is titled index.html

But if you do need to use Heroku for whatever reason, [here is a guide on how to do so](https://gist.github.com/wh1tney/2ad13aa5fbdd83f6a489). It shows how to create the composer.json and index.php needed for a static site.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform these steps:-

**1)** Add a file called `composer.json` to the root directory by running `touch composer.json`

**2)** Add a file called `index.php` to the root directory by running `touch index.php`

**3)** Rename the homepage (e.g. index.html) to `home.html`

**4)** In `index.php`, add the following line: `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`

**5)** In `composer.json`, add the following line: {}

**6)** Run `git push heroku master`

**OR**

While being in your website directory run these commands

**1)** $ `echo '{}' > composer.json`

**2)** $ `echo '<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>' > index.php`

**3)** $ `mv index.html home.html`(If you already have a HTML file name `index`)

Thanks to [@wh1tney](https://gist.github.com/wh1tney)
Here is the link to her post.

Link:- https://gist.github.com/wh1tney/2ad13aa5fbdd83f6a489

Comment: `echo '{}' > composer.json` is wrong. RTM: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the these steps:

1. Rename your `index.html` file to home.html
2. Create a file called `index.php` in the root directory
3. Write the following line in the file `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`
4. Now, create a file called `composer.json` and write the follwing line in it: {}
5. Now say $ git add.
6. $ git commit -m "deploying static--err, dynamic site to heroku"
7. heroku login

> Enter your Heroku credentials:
>   Email: `<YOUR HEROKU EMAIL>`
>   Password: `<YOUR HEROKU PASSWORD>`

8. heroku create
9. heroku git:remote -a
10. git push heroku master

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simpler strategy**:

Navigate to your project in the command prompt:

```
cd Projects/my-site
```

Log in to heroku in your terminal or command prompt:

```
heroku login
```

**Note**: Do not rename the `index.html` file to `home.html`. This will not fit in for this strategy.

Create an `index.php` file and insert this one line of code (`<?php header( 'Location: /index.html'` ) ;  ?> into it:

```
echo '<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>' index.php
```

Add the changes to git:

```
git init
git add .
```

Then you want to commit or save all the changes for your site. With a message describing what you’ve done.

```
git commit -m "my site ready for deployment"
```

Now you want to create your site on Heroku. If you’re already logged in (because you ran `heroku login` earlier), you can issue the following command:

```
heroku apps:create my-static-site
```

Insert your desired name instead of `my-static-site`.

If the name isn’t taken you can deploy your site using `git`.

```
git push heroku master
```

You can now visit your site at `https://<whatever-name-you-selected>.herokuapp.com/` or my example site here `https://my-static-site.herokuapp.com/`.

If you need to, make changes to your site of the following 3 commands.

Add the changes…

```
git add .
```

Save the changes…

```
git commit -m "add useful message"
```

Then deploy…

```
git push heroku master
```

**Resource**: [How to Deploy a Static Site to Heroku](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution I have found is, with a home page `home.html`, to create a single-line `index.php` file:

`<?php include_once('home.html'); ?>`

---

I recently found that `home.html` should be enclosed in single quotes and not double quotes.  Originally I had been deploying a version with `include_once("home.html")` instead of `include_once('home.html')` and around the same time Heroku eliminated their free tier the server started to throw the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "“home" in /app/index.php:1`

Making the change from `"home.html"` to `'home.html'` fixed the problem.