# Can't deploy html css and js app to heroku, "NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.lock; using PHP ^7.0.0"

Tags: php, html, heroku, deployment

I have a simple project which has just an html, a folder with a css file, another folder with a js file, and another with images. In order to deploy it to heroku, I read I had to create the index.php, require the home.html and create a composer.json with only a `{}` in it, as it says: [Uploading a static site on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935514/uploading-a-static-site-on-heroku)

When I use the command `git push heroku master` to deploy it, it complains about this:`NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.lock; using PHP ^7.0.0`., and the project is not available on the link provided.

If it helps, my project's structure is as simple as this:

[image]

I don't know if that Notice is just a warning, but I find it very strange that Heroku can't deploy such a simple project.

Comment: Why would you use Heroku for a static site? There are definitely better options out there for that. Heroku is for running _applications_.

Comment: A [notice is not a warning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Comment: @Chris which better ones do you recommend me? thanks

Comment: Asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a web host, is off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. But there are *man* options. Search for "static site hosting" and pick one.

Comment: I was getting still more errors (of versions and with the procfile, with the composer.json requiring name property...) so I decided to do it with githubpages, as it was much simpler and I don't need to know any php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you were suggested to use just `{}`, as the doc says to use the following within `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

Please move your index.php to folder and point via Procfile. Also make sure that your composer.json is valid.